# Image is showing in gallery but after restarting emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-gallery

I have implemented an application in which  I am downloading an image from a url and storing it on an SD card.
 It is showing in the emulator gallery after restarting it. Is it possible to show images in a gallery without restarting emulator?

Comment: What you need exactly..?? Didn't get you clearly...

Comment: I am downloading an image and storing it in SD card. now it should show in gellary also. but its not showing until restart emulator. I want that it should show without restarting emulator.

Comment: Make use of MediaStore for updating the SDCard media content..

Comment: mr kartik will you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approaches:

#1 If you want immediate results then make use of MediaScannerConnection.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx,new String[] { path.toString() },null,new    MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {    

  public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {    
    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");    
    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);   
  }   
});
```

#2   If you don't need immediate results(eg. you have created new 100s of images) then instead when you are done downloading all the files you could trigger a scan yourself of the entire SD card by telling the system that the card was just mounted:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Conclusion : If you are writing very small no. of files at a time then make use of #1 otherwise #1 is fast when you are dealing with writing very large no. of files which are to be scanned.